# Write MMult function in excel via R script

Tags: r, openxlsx

I'm using R to create a set of matrixes than I need to publish in an excel workbook.
The final result is a matrix (M) and a vector (X) and a vector (Y), where M*X=Y. The "user" of the workbook will modify the X vector to view the impact on Y.

I'm using the openxlsx library to create the excel workbook from the R script. But I haven't found a way of writing the MMult formula that calculates the Y vector to the result workbook.

Is there a way to write the MMult formula? Or what other strategy could I use?

I hope the explanation wasn't too convoluted.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `openxlsx::writeFormula`?

Comment: Yes, but writing it like a normal formula doesn't seem to work. From de Microsoft support page "the formula must be entered as a legacy array formula by first selecting the output range, entering the formula in the top-left-cell of the output range, and then pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to confirm it. Excel inserts curly brackets at the beginning and end of the formula for you. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Up front:** if I'm interpreting you correctly, then *this is not currently supported*.

### What does work

```r
library(openxlsx)
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet1")
writeData(wb = wb, sheet = "Sheet1", x = matrix(1:6, ncol = 2), startCol = 1)
writeData(wb = wb, sheet = "Sheet1", x = matrix(7:12, nrow = 2), startCol = 4)
writeFormula(wb = wb, sheet = "Sheet1", x = "MMULT(A2:B4, D2:F3)", startCol = 8, array = T)
saveWorkbook(wb = wb, file = "quux.xlsx")
```

[image: excel with single-cell MMULT]

If I click on `H1`, edit it (do nothing) and hit enter, this becomes:

[image: excel with multi-cell MMULT]

Imperfect, but at least to get it working does not take significant effort. Since it appears this is for a user to explore changing one of the vectors, it may not be too onerous to say *"... click in `$H$1`, click `Fn-2` (edit), hit `Enter`"*.

(Interesting side note: it does *not* impose the `{...}` curly braces around the formula that normally denote an array-formula. Editing the field and pressing `Shift-Control-Enter` does add the braces, same numeric results.)

### Background

It appears the premise of adding formulas was added in Jan 2021, as [PR #131](https://github.com/ycphs/openxlsx/pull/131). Unfortunately, the author of the PR (since merged) replied [3 months later](https://github.com/ycphs/openxlsx/pull/131#issuecomment-813640532) with this very point: it requires editing the cell to get it to expand to the full matrix.

Since the issue is merged and there has been a bit of work since that PR, I suspect that either the maintainer(s) have forgotten about comments on a merged PR, or perhaps they aren't interested in fixing it. I suggest it might be useful for you to raise a new issue and perhaps pinging the two other commenters in #131 to get their support, comments, etc.

Comment: I would be happy with the solution you are proposing, but for me, the formula just appears in the one cell, H1 in your example, even after the edit and enter.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know, make sure you're using `openxlsx-4.2.5.1`? I'm using win11 and Excel from Office365 (recent install, so up-to-date), perhaps your problem is in some combination of versions not covered. It works for me with my data and my code here, though: given we have none of that for your specific use-case, I don't think I can do any better. Good luck.

Comment: Now that you mention Office365 I believe that is the key difference. From https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mmult-function-40593ed7-a3cd-4b6b-b9a3-e4ad3c7245eb
Note: If you have a current version of Microsoft 365, then you can simply enter the formula in the top-left-cell of the output range, then press ENTER to confirm the formula as a dynamic array formula. Otherwise, the formula must be entered as a legacy array formula

Comment: I think I will be going with your solution but with extra steps. I need to select all te result range and CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: Can't you just edit `$H$1` and press `C-S-Enter`? I don't know that you need to highlight the full anticipated target range ... it's been a while since I've had monolithic Excel installed, sorry.

Comment: No, that generates a single value, the full range needs to be selected.

Comment: Okay, well ... unfortunately then that is what you must do. I'll reiterate, though, that it would be a good thing (imho) to submit an issue on `openxlsx` to finish that use-case of `writeFormula`. It makes a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

@r2evans to provide a little more insight to your detailed answer: The issue is due to the fact, that the cell reference is unknown to `openxlsx`. To know this, one would have to evaluate the formula in R to measure the reference area and pass this to the xml sheet. This is currently not done and would require someone to write a function parser Excel formulas to R functions ... guess we all have better things to do.

To demonstrate the behavior have a look at the following `openxlsx2` example:

```r
library(openxlsx2)

m1 <- matrix(1:6, ncol = 2)
m2 <- matrix(7:12, nrow = 2)

wb <- wb_workbook()$add_worksheet()$
  add_data(x = m1, startCol = 1)$
  add_data(x = m2, startCol = 4)$
  add_formula(dims = "H1", x = "MMULT(A2:B4, D2:F3)", array = TRUE)

# matrix multiplication
mm <- m1 %*% m2

# modify cc (internal dataframe of worksheet data; danger, danger!)

# add the full reference from H1 to ...
wb$worksheets[[1]]$sheet_data$cc[6, "f_ref"] <- "H1:J3"

# # check the output
# wb$open()
```